# How to create a world map using C language?

Tags: c, procedural-generation, world-map

How to create a world map using C language?

Here, I want to generate a 1000*1000 two dimensional array of world map. Within the array, the land part is marked with value 1 and the sea part is marked with value 0. Is there any simple way to create?

Comment: Of course: `int world[1000][1000] = { {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, ...},{0, 0, 0, 1, ...}, ...};`

Comment: You mean terrain generation? A simple and okay-ish way is the [Diamond-Square algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond-square_algorithm).

Comment: You only need 1000*1000/8 bytes. One byte is 8 bits.

Comment: have you looked at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/platec/; https://github.com/bapt/cplanet or https://github.com/Mindwerks/worldengine ?

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, there's no algorithm which describes the shape of the coastline of the continents ;)

But you could use e.g. Smrender (http://www.abenteuerland.at/smrender/), feed it with the coastline of e.g. OpenStreetMap or Naturalearthdata and a single rule. Let it create a PNG image with 1000x1000 pixels.

EDIT:
With ImageMagick (convert) you can directly convert a PNG into a C header file as an array.
Go to Openstreetmap.org (or Googlemaps), zoom out until you see the whole world, make a screenshot, open it in your favorite image manipulation program and cut and resize it to 1000x1000, then run `convert input.png output.h`.

Bernhard

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a answer in game development some hours ago that can help you, heres the [topic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/114767/procedural-dungeon-generation-connect-rooms-with-passageways), it's written in javascript, but it won't be hard to translate to c.

In the example you fill the whole map of 0's and then you trace a path randomly, if you want to smooth the map later you can make a snippet that loops all the watter tiles and converts them to land if there are 3 or more land tiles adjacent to it, do it 40-60 times and you will get a smoother shore and no "holes" in the continent.

EDIT
Updating the answer with a demo in C.
I've not tested it, but if you include the headers and checks the code, this is the answer.

```
//Create and populate the map
int mapsize = 100;
int map[mapsize*mapsize];

for(int t = 0; t < mapsize*mapsize; t++) map[t] = 0;

//make the path
int currPos[2] = {0,50};
map[currPos[0]+(currPos[1]*mapSize)] = 1;
int landTiles = 20000;

for(var l = 0; l < landTiles; l++){
    int dir[2] = {RANDOM_BETWEEN_-1_AND_1, RANDOM_BETWEEN_-1_AND_1};
    int next[2] = {currPos[0]+dir[0], currPos[1]+dir[1]};

    map[next[0]+(next[1]*mapSize)] = 1;
    currPos = next;
}

//Draw the map
for(var row = 0; row < mapSize; row++){
    for(var col = 0; col < mapSize; col++){
        cout << map[col+(row*mapSize)];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanku sir.. Is there any more simple way to create?

Comment: Indeed, the technique is really simple, the implementation that i did is really tricky, it was a test, so its hard to understand.
You only have to populate the map with 0's, choose a random init poiint, loop lot of times (20000 in the example), in each loop the script has to choose a random direction, set a land tile in that position and update that position as the "current", that will give you what you saw in the demo

Answer (score 0):

You could have some program or script (taking as input some representation of some image of the Earth) which generates a long C file like

```
const char map[1000][1000] = {
  {'0', '1', //.... etc for the first fow
  },
  {'0', '0', '0', '1', //... etc
  }
  /// etc for other rows
};
```

See also [XBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_BitMap) for an example.